# Angular template: Is there something like {{someObject.someList.where(somePredicate).length}}?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frameworks, client-side

When doing templating in angular, is there a way to filter a list before displaying its length? Can I do, for exemple, something like `<h3>{{category.products.where(p => p.IsActive).length}}</h3>`?

If not, what are the best alternatives?

Comment: custom filters are your friend in this case.

Comment: Can it filter on an object's sublist? If so, how do they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement right, you need to do something as done in the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/D9UXJGM1cIvlrijXDro6?p=preview) I have created.

If your requirement is different, could you demonstrate that using a plunkr?

```
{{ (user.products | active).length }} products
```

Abhi

Comment: This is not what I need. I don't need a ng-repeat. What I need would be, in you example, the number of active products in user.

I don't need to loop, I need to get the number of active products in user.

Comment: Once you have got a filtered set, you can do whatever you want with it. Plunkr and answer now updated to show count of filtered items.

Comment: I get an error: "Unknown provider: IsActiveFilterProvider <- IsActiveFilter"

Comment: I cannot say what the problem is without looking at your code. Can you submit a plunkr for this? As you can see, the filter works fine in my plunkr.

Comment: I can't paste my actual code since it is code from my workplace.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron It sounds like you have the filter on the angular binding but that it can't find the filter defined in your code. Do the names of the filter match up on the the binding `{{ (user.products | IsActive).length }}` and somewhere in your code `app.filter("IsActive", function () { ...`

Comment: I did not know I needed to add a function too. I thought angular would look at the property IsActive of my products. I'm trying that, thx.

Comment: I second Marc on this. Check the names in the filter definition and the usage.

Comment: I would recommend going through the documentation on filters here - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: This works now. Thank to both of you. Double thank for you Abhishek for your patience.

Comment: No problem at all. :-)